# error en formatear la fecha en python

Tags: python, date, formato

tengo un codigo en python que lo quiero hacer es darle formato a la fecha del json y no consigo hacerlo :(, este es el codigo...

```py
import requests
import os
import datetime
import locale

Habbo = input("Escribe el nombre del keko: ") 

response = requests.get(f'https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users/{Habbo}/profile')

Habbo = response.json()["user"]["memberSince"]

date_time_str = '2011-10-21T11:53:29.000+0000'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)

archivo = open ("Habbo.html","a")
archivo.write(str(Habbo))    
archivo.close()
```

No lo puedo hacer funcionar, aqui dejo una captura:

[image: Error python]

Json: https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name=sefos

A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Estabas casi allí. El parsing de los instantes de acuerdo a la [norma ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)  suelen dar problemas. Te faltaba agregar al formato lo siguiente:

- El señalador de la hora (`T`)
- La directiva `%z` referente al adelanto o atraso UTC.

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import datetime


datetime_string = '2011-10-21T11:53:29.000+0000'
iso_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    datetime_string,
    iso_format
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó pero ahora el problema que no puedo modificar el separador por ejemplo: 02/07/2013, al intentarlo me da error

Comment: Pues sustituye los guiones (`-`) con slashes (`/`) en la variable `iso_format` y listo.

Comment: Si, eso hice pero me da error mira: https://i.imgur.com/Y2bu1N6.gif

Comment: Cambiaste el formato (en mi ejemplo: `iso_format`), pero no la fecha (en mi ejemplo: `datetime_string`). Obviamente dará error. O sea, el formato especificado tiene que coincidir con el formato que viene dado en la fecha. Si la fecha tiene guiones, el formato debe tenerlos. Si la fecha tiene slashes, el formato debe tenerlos. Ambos deben coincidir.